# Looking if the following series has a closed form

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

While solving a problem, I encounter a series that can be solved if we know whether

$$ f(x) = \sum_{n \geq 0 } \dfrac{ 2^{n} x^{2^{n}} }{ 1- x^{2^n} } $$

Is there a way to find a closed form for that series? I was thinking perhaps to write the numerator as $x^{2^n} -1 +1 $ but then I would end up with $\sum 2^n$ which is divergent.

Comment: You sequence $a_n(x)=\dfrac{d}{dx}(1/2\ln(1-x^{2^n}) $

Comment: But do we find closed form for $\sum ln(1-x^{2^n}) ?$

Comment: Yes transform it in product

Comment: oh, you mean using the geometric formula to expand $1-x^{2^n}$?

Comment: I'm meaning $\sum\ln=\ln(\prod)) $

Comment: Sure, but I still dont see a closed for for $\prod_{n=0}^{\infty} (1-x^{2^n}) $

Comment: If it were $\prod (1+x^{2^n})$ is a lot easier as we can write $1+x^{2^n} = \dfrac{1-x^{2^{n+1}}}{1-x^{2^n} } $ but this case I dont see a way

Comment: Actually $(1-x^{2^n})=(1-x)\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(1+x^{2^k})$ but it goes to the beginning

Comment: We know that $\sum_{k=0}^N \ln(1+x^{2^n}) \sim_{N\rightarrow \infty} -\ln(1-x) \sim \sum_{k=0}^Nx^{2n} $ from the development of $ln(1+x)=x+O(x^2)$ . So if my deduction is right $\sum_{k=0}^N \ln(1-x^{2^n}) \sim \sum_{k=0}^Nx^{2n} \sim \ln(1-x) $ It seems some incompleteness here. But maybe the idea os asymptotic development is right idea !

Comment: The first sentence of this question seems to be missing something: "... a series that can be solved if we know whether" followed by a definition of a function "$f(x)=\ldots$". Whether _what_? Which property of $f(x)$ are you looking for? Convergence for some particular values of $x$? Some upper or lower bounds?